# Custom "Floating" UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have been searching the web for an answer to this and I am sure it has an easy answer.

I am creating an UITableView in my app and I am wanting it to have "floating" table view cells and a menu at the top. Like this:

[image]

I am sure that these are custom UITableView Cells, but I am not sure how to create them like this and have them be dynamic in size based on the content and how to include a menu at the top that disappears/shows once the user scrolls down or up.

Any insight on this would be awesome!

Comment: I don't think they are UITableView cells... I think they are just UIViews nested inside of a UIScrollView. I don't think it has anything to do with a UITableView... rather there is probably a for-loop that just generates a bunch of vies and spaces them out accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by floating? Do you mean this "look", or are you talking about some kind of behavior of the cells.

Comment: The menu just looks like a custom UIView / UIViewController while the main area looks like a UICollectionView with custom UICollectionViewCells.  I would Google for example code based on these types.

Comment: That app most definitely is using proper UITableViewCells with all their nifty queuing. Dynamic table row heights are really trivial to implement (check the UITableView delegate methods).

Answer (score 4):

This can be done fairly easily with a subclassed UITableViewCell in a grouped table view. The image below shows one I quickly made by dragging in various UI elements, and creating a custom class, which has nothing but IBOutlets in the .h file.

[image]

The label with the gibberish in it is tied to the gray view below and to the top of the cell, with no specific height set, so when the cell grows, it will grow. Here is the code I used to populate the table:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.theData = @[@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four",@"Five",@"Six",@"Seven",@"Eight",@"Nine"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   return  self.theData.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *s = @"asdfhfl fl flfh sflhsalfjh fajlhf lf asldf fh asljfafh sjlfh ajf fljf fasjlfhjfhjfhjsf hsjfhsjfhajsfh the end";
    CGSize size = [s sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(281, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return size.height + 130;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RDCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.lbl1.text = self.theData[indexPath.section];
    cell.lbl2.text = @"asdfhfl fl flfh sflhsalfjh fajlhf lf asldf fh asljfafh sjlfh ajf fljf fasjlfhjfhjfhjsf hsjfhsjfhajsfhajlfjafh";
    return cell;
}
```

Notice that I set the number of sections to the count of the array, so you get separate sections of 1 row each. The code in the heightForRowAtIndexPath is typical of the way you would calculate the cell height (except that you would normally use the index path and get a different string for each cell).

Answer (score 0):

I think thats what you are looking for.. 
[IBScrollViewFloatingHeader](https://github.com/ivanbruel/IBScrollViewFloatingHeader)